# Horizontally Centering SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I can't seem to be able to horizontally center my SVG logo.

This is my CSS:

```
html body div.body-container div#logo {
    position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; float: none; clear: both;
    width: 100%; max-width: 100%; height: 150px; margin: 0; padding: 0;
    background-image: url(vulco-logo.min.png); background-position: center center; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: 175px 55px;
    background-color: rgba(26, 60, 88, 0.9);
    z-index: 20;
}
html body div.body-container div#logo svg {
    position: relative; float: left; clear: none; display: block;
    width: auto; height: 60px; margin: 0 auto; padding: 0; text-align: center;
    fill: #ffffff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="logo"><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 158.172 50" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" preserveAspectRatio="xMixYMid meet">



</svg></div>
```

I've tried display block and margin auto. I've tried text-align center, nothing.
Am I overlooking something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. Seems `float: left;` was causing all the trouble.